# SQL Удалить все совпадения из таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

У меня в большом количестве ячеек хранится инлайновый стиль к `style="text-decoration: line-through !important;"` подскажите, как можно обойти все ячейки и удалить данные стили? Пробовал через замену

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`, ‘style="text-decoration: line-through !important;" ‘, ‘ ‘);
```

Но не срабатывает
[image: mysql reqest]

Comment: проблема явно в каких то видах кавычек, но вот как раз кавычки в приведенном текстом запросе и на картинке не совпадают (перед style вообще нет ничего, а в последнем параметре какие то utf символы явно не поддерживаемые mysql). приведите текст запроса как есть, а лучше сами посмотрите что у вас там за кавычки, убедитесь что текст и проблем в обычных одиночных апострафах

Comment: Я вообще не силен в sql . Разные тут варианты опробовал / Нужно. ли оба значения (и то по которому ищем, и то на которое хотим заменить) брать в кавычки?

Answer (score -1):

Добрые люди подсказали, что надо делать экранирование / Особенность mySQL

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`, "style=""text-decoration: line-through !important;" , " ");
```

Comment: *Добрые люди подсказали, что надо делать экранирование* Это они от безысходности, наверное... строковые литералы в MySQL обрамляются **одинарной кавычкой `'`**, а не двойной. И никакого нафиг тут экранирования не нужно, ибо при использовании правильных кавычек на данном литерале никаких требующих экранирования символов просто нет.